# How to retrieve RTT from sockets created by wget in C++ programming?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to get the round trip time (RTT) from socket statistics using C++ program in Ubuntu. There is not much resources online. How can I go about getting the RTT, or perhaps there is a better alternative to socket statistic? Many thanks in advance.

Update:
I followed the lead given by jxh. I created a socket and tested out the code. It worked out fine. However, since I originally use wget, I do not have the file descriptor of the socket. I was hoping to get the RTT from sockets that were created by the system. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: A better alternative *for what purpose?*

Comment: What are socket statistics?

Comment: While there has been [proposals](https://github.com/arielshaqed/collectd/commit/0bf7f03c4f93a7fdc010ec7e417a1377dd70a92b) for driver-level collection of socket statistics, I don't know of any in shipping systems.  Anyway, what the driver could do amounts to pretty much a ping - you can undoubtedly find a library or write a ping program yourself.  At an application level, RTT depends much more on the server and client responsiveness and the sizes of messages involved: you have to time that within your app, as the TCP stream is a byte protocol unaware of your message boundaries.

Comment: There really isn't anything wrong with this question.

Comment: @jxh There really isn't anything wrong with the question except that (i) the OP hasn't addressed any of the comments and (ii) the part about an alternative is meaningless until he does so.

Answer (score 1):

As Ubuntu is a Linux system, you can use the system specific [`TCP_INFO` socket option](http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp):

> **`TCP_INFO`** (since Linux 2.4)
>
> > Used  to  collect  information  about  this  socket.  The kernel
> >                   returns   a   `struct tcp_info`   as   defined   in   the   file
> >                   `/usr/include/linux/tcp.h`.   This  option  should  not be used in
> >                   code intended to be portable.

The referenced structure has a member named `tcpi_rtt`, which seems like it would be what you want.

```
struct tcp_info info;
socklen_t info_len = sizeof(info);
int r = getsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_INFO, &info, &info_len);
// examine info.tcpi_rtt ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the lead. It was of great help. Unfortunately, I do not have the file descriptor (sock). I am using wget to start the socket and I am trying to find the file descriptor. Perhaps you have some insights on how to do it?

Comment: Option 1: `wget` is open-source, so you can modify the code. Option 2: You can build a library that intercepts the, say, `send()` system call, and read `TCP_INFO` before doing the real send.

Comment: Would it be better to get the file descriptor from `/proc/[PID]/fd` so I can use `getsockopt()`?

Comment: I already described your best options. If you want to explore a different way, ask a new question.